# How to turn off overlays if I can't touch the screen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, developer-options, overlay, touch, samsung-galaxy-pocket

My cell phone is a Samsung Galaxy Pocket 2 (SM-G110B/DS) running Android 4.4 KitKat. I found the developer options, and "by mistake", I selected one of the overlays. The problem is that the overlay has a bigger resolution than what my screen supports, and it doesn't let me touch the screen (Overlay #1 1280x720).

I have turned the phone off and on again and it didn't work, I took off the battery, pinched it, and tapped on it several times... nothing changed, but that overlay is still there and doesn't let me touch the screen.

How can I turn this overlay off?

Comment: Weird, it works on my phone, so I thought it would work on yours as well. Seems to be a new thing added in Lollipop.

Comment: @GiantTree So how do I reset it?

Comment: Does your usb debugging mode enable in your developer options menu? Related [Adb shell commands to change settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203495/adb-shell-commands-to-change-settings-or-perform-tasks-on-a-phone?rq=1)

Comment: @Lucky  well, I can't see it because you know the overlay thing :D, but when I connect it via USB it appears as phone camera, not USB storage, so I can't access anything in my phone. BTW the only thing I see is the lock screen behind the overlay, sorry I forgot to tag you before

Comment: I have just experienced something similar. Have you tried navigating the phone using a physical keyboard (you might need a USB adapter for this) then launching an app that causes your phone to change orientation? What about rebooting into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to disable the display overlay via ADB

```
adb shell settings put global overlay_display_devices null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I long-pressed on the *overlay#1* window, dragged it down, and then turned off the *Developer options*.

Hope it helps in a way.