# Start Chromium at web page with ActivityManager

Tags: chromium

I've got Chromium 106 installed on my phone and can successfully launch it via

```
$ adb shell am start -n org.chromium.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

However, when I try to bring up a specific page at launch time with

```
$ adb shell am start -n org.chromium.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

(I've got a web server running on port 8080 on my host with reverse TCP forwarding set up.)

the app doesn't launch but I get the error

```
Starting: Intent { dat=http://127.0.0.1:8080 cmp=org.chromium.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.chromium.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main} does not exist.
```

Is this not the right way to use `am` with Chromium?

Note: The command works if I run under `su -c`.

Comment: Try changing the activity name to `org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity` and put the URL in double quotes. Source: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241012/96277

Comment: You mean `org.chromium.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity`?  Same error.