# what is the standard editor in Android?

Tags: adb, command-line, text-editor

I'm connecting to this Google phone via `adb`, I need to change a character inside of a text file, and I would use `vi`, or maybe `sed -i`, or even `pico` if nothing else helps, but I don't find any well known CLI editor.

How do you Android Enthusiasts do this?  I mean, short of copying the file back and forth?

```
/system/bin/sh: vi: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # pico
/system/bin/sh: pico: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # nano
/system/bin/sh: nano: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # vim
/system/bin/sh: vim: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # sed
/system/bin/sh: sed: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # emacs
/system/bin/sh: emacs: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ # apropos editor
/system/bin/sh: apropos: not found
127|root@generic_x86:/ #
```

Comment: There isn't any standard editor - you use what works for you. You can search for one Izzy's list [Notes] (https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes) or better [text editors for developers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_105)

Comment: To clarify, Android doesn't have any built in editor

Comment: hi, thanks, I feared so much.  But these lists only have graphic editors, to be used from the android screen itself, isn't it?  I had hoped for some CLI tools. (I'll have a look at the Vim port, I guess. thank you again.)

Comment: Have a look at this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44049/131553

Comment: @mariotomo Did you try to launch `vim` or `nano`? I run LineageOS and can start them.

Comment: I am inside of a virtual android machine, I do not know what is LineageOS, and I've not mentioned all that I tried, which indeed included `vim` and `nano`.
https://github.com/shiftrot/droidvim/issues/19

Comment: Try out [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux).

Comment: thank you for the hint on Termux, I will definitely try it on my physical phone.  but I'm currently on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, I would be happy with `sed`.
Still as later mentioned in a comment, I am in a virtual environment, so no trouble dropping one OS and start using the newer one.

Apparently, my problem was staying in Android 5.1.  Starting version 6 Android includes `ToyBox`, a rather limited alternative to `BusyBox`, legally compatible with the non-free license of Android.

The `ToyBox` hint comes from the author of [droidvim](https://github.com/shiftrot/droidvim/).